# Where should the file user.clj go?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, atom-editor, proto-repl

I am trying to setup proto-repl atom-editor package and apparently it needs a file user.clj to exist somewhere - which I guess is some leiningen's init file.

Where should I create this file?

Comment: `user.clj`, if present, defines the default clojure namespace. Leiningen's init file is project.clj.

Comment: What leads you to think that user.clj is needed?

Comment: A nasty error on the proto repl complaining about it's unexistence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clojure will load the file `user.clj` from your class path if it is found. In a default leinengen project `src/` will be on the class path, so if you create `src/user.clj` the contents of that file will be loaded in the context of the `user` namespace.

`user` is the default namespace for the clojure repl, but some leiningen projects override this. In order to access definitions in `user.clj` you will need to either pull `user` into scope (using `require` or `use`) or make sure that `user` is your starting namespace.

Comment: I'm wondering why this was downvoted. `user.clj` is loaded based on the classpath, the first `user.clj` that is found will be loaded to define the `user` namespace. The information here might not be sufficient for explaining `proto-repl`, but user.clj is a clojure feature, not a leiningen or proto-repl one.

Comment: Because it's a real clj file in the project, not the user.clj for leiningen... :D

Comment: user.clj is a real file, it's loaded by clojure, not leinengen or anything else

Answer (score 2):

See the Proto REPL demo project https://github.com/jasongilman/proto-repl-demo/blob/master/dev/user.clj for an example of how to setup user.clj You should also add a dependency on clojure.tools.namespace in the project.clj https://github.com/jasongilman/proto-repl-demo/blob/master/project.clj

I just pushed some changes to Proto REPL last night to improve this area but you'll still benefit from having one setup.

Answer (score 1):

According to the proto-repl page, it might use some functions from `user` namespace when reloading code in REPL (`reset` function) but it shouldn't be required.

You might want to take a look at the [proto-repl demo project](https://github.com/jasongilman/proto-repl-demo) to see the more advanced setup.