# Heroku, Clojure - Connecting to Database Outside Heroku

Tags: heroku, clojure

I am trying to connect to a Database on a Heroku Dyno from outside of Heroku in Clojure.

From the Heroku guides it says to create a connection `DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a your-app) your_process`

From my application I did `DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a my-app) lein repl` and then `(System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")` and saw that the Database URL was correct.

My question is how would I set the DATABASE_URL from within the app. So instead of doing `DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a my-app) lein repl` to connect to the database, I can just do `lein repl` or `lein run` and it connects. Do I have to put `DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a my-app)` in a Config file within my app. If I did it this way I don't have a process either. Is that necessary?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: are you saying you don't want to use env vars at all? or have you tried `export DATABASE_URL="$(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

For `lein repl` the code that will run is in user.clj, where this file can be under the directory dev, which will have to be included in `:source-paths` in the project.clj file. The use of dev is a convention I seem to have picked up (from Untangled). The use of user.clj is however baked into lein. See [Where should the file user.clj go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235176/where-should-the-file-user-clj-go). You might want a dev profile for this as well. I know I'm a bit vague here, others might be able to do better - here's a simple project.clj that works for me: https://github.com/chrismurrph/Accounting/blob/master/project.clj.

`lein run` will however run completely different code. See http://www.flyingmachinestudios.com/programming/how-clojure-babies-are-made-lein-run/ (or http://www.braveclojure.com/getting-started/) and note that the `-main` that is run needs to be specified in your project.clj file - in the linked text the configuration/starup code is specified with the entry: `:main learn-a-language.important-phrases`.